# awesomeWM vicious volume progress widgit

Tags: awesome, widgets

I have included at the end some `rc.lua` code copied nearly verbatim from vicious README examples. (The set_color line needed an additional "}" and I changed BAT0 to BAT1).

`awmtt.sh` gives me an error:

```
/usr/share/awesome/lib/awful/widget/progressbar.lua:188: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)
```

If I go to the file in question, it is trying to access `data[progressbar].height`,
suggesting data has no member progressbar.

Ubuntu 14.04, awesomeWM 3.4. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
batwidget=awful.widget.progressbar()
batwidget.set_height(10)
batwidget.set_width(8)
batwidget.set_vertical(true)
batwidget:set_background_color("#494B4F")
batwidget:set_border_color(nil)
batwidget:set_color({ type = "linear", from = { 0, 0 }, to = { 0, 10 },
     stops = { { 0, "#AECF96" }, { 0.5, "#88A175" }, { 1, "#FF5656" }}})
vicious.register(batwidget, vicious.widgets.bat, "$2", 61, "BAT1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot check it myself at the moment, but if you look [here in the awesome wiki](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Vicious#Memory_usage_.28progressbar.29) you can see that you use the syntax for awesome 3.5 instead of 3.4 at the `batwidget:setcolor` line.

Also,

```
batwidget.set_height(10)
batwidget.set_width(8)
batwidget.set_vertical(true)`
```

should be

```
batwidget:set_height(10)
batwidget:set_width(8)
batwidget:set_vertical(true)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your two comments were spot on. Thanks for helping a newb along the learning curve.